# fullpage.js return to homepage scrambled

Tags: wordpress, fullpage.js

I have created a landing homepage in wordpress (index.php) that uses fullpage.js. This page also has subpage links that lead to outside pages (which are not integrated to the index.php).

When I click to the main links everything is ok, it rolls perfectly (and I love the key and mousescroll implementation). But when I push back from the subpage to go to the original link, or from the menu (see code below), every page is scrambled. It does not continue from the point I clicked the sublink but it regards it as the starting point rendering all above pages useless to navigate.

in my homepage (index.php) my links are created in the following format:

```
<div class="menu-navigation">
<ul class="menu">
 <li class="[wordpress classes] active"><a href="#slide1">Slide 1</a></li>
 <li class="[wordpress classes]"><a href="#slide2">Slide 2</a></li>
 <li class="[wordpress classes]"><a href="#slide3">Slide 3</a></li>
 <li class="[wordpress classes]"><a href="#slide4">Slide 4</a></li>
 <li class="[wordpress classes]"><a href="#slide5">Slide 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<section id="#slide1" class="section active">
[content]
</section>
<section id="#slide2" class="section">
[content]
</section>
<section id="#slide3" class="section">
[content]
</section>
<section id="#slide4" class="section">
[content]
</section>
<section id="#slide5" class="section">
[content]
</section>
```

The only difference is that when I jump to a sublink page the menu becomes:

```
<div class="menu-navigation">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="[wordpress classes]"><a href="index.php#slide1">Slide 1</a></li>
<li class="[wordpress classes]"><a href="index.php#slide2">Slide 2</a></li>
<li class="[wordpress classes]"><a href="index.php#slide3">Slide 3</a></li>
<li class="[wordpress classes]"><a href="index.php#slide4">Slide 4</a></li>
<li class="[wordpress classes]"><a href="index.php#slide5">Slide 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

As far as I can tell it's because my implementation uses hash, which is lost between back and forth. Is there a way to show the hash on the url?

Answer (score 0):

As detailed [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#options) for the menu option:

> Be careful! if you use anchors, they can not have the same value as any ID element on the site (or NAME element for IE).

So, you should avoid using id elements such as #slide1, #slide2... etc.

Comment: Actually it was example code. Mine are #panel-{wordpress-post-ID} style

Comment: @Panagiotis could you then paste your real resulting HTML code? (not the PHP one `#panel-{wordpress-post-ID}`...)